# SQLPlus - Formatting of query output

Tags: sqlplus

I have an SQL assignment for UNI due in a couple days. I played around with SQL settings using the 'set' command and I have messed up the output of queries (see screenshots, link below).

The output seems to be writing to a fixed line length, instead of using the full length of the terminal console. I am using tmux in iterm v3.2 but also have the same issue on the native MAC OSX terminal.

Is there a way to reset these settings to default? Or somehow make it work for me? I just want the lines to be displayed to the right side of the screen, until it needs to be wrapped.

Let me know if this is a dupe.

[image: SELECT output]

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. Each of those lines is one word long. You'll notice there are 14 lines and at the end it says `14 rows selected`.

Comment: Why does it show two sections though?

Example:
Table_name
Abc
123
....
Ggg

Table_name
Dhs
....
Zzz

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know that - somewhere there is a limit of 11 rows set before outputting a new title row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

This is controlled by the pagesize environment variable.
For the screenshot I had pagesize set to 14. Which means print 14 lines, with a blank line for the 14th line, before printing the rest of the output.

I changed the pagesize value to 200, this should be enough for what I need.

```
set pagesize n

help set
```

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer. This could be useful to other people and it should rank higher as an accepted answer.

Comment: Absolutley I will, forgot to get back to it as I was working on my assignment all day yesterday.. The 24 hour restriction is weird, I couldn't accept it after writing it for ankther 24 hours.

Comment: Well no rush. They do have  a longer limit on accepting your own answer to encourage others to answer as well.